# Login System JSF - Identified an SQLException?

Tags: java, mysql, database, web

Well thanks to the people who actually tried helping me but I found out what my problem was in the end: MYSQL script caused it to search for "Admin1" which is my login id when it should have searched username and password so had to modify my query to do so. I'll leave my solution for future apprentices.

```
    public void dbData(String UName, String PWord) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/unidb?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "Safia10122014");
        String SQL = "select `Username`, `Password` from `SPAS_Login_Details` where `Username` like 'MWR0025'";

        Statement statement = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
        resultSet.next();
        dbUname = resultSet.getString(1);
        dbPword = resultSet.getString(2);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public String validation() {
    dbData(name, password);

    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(dbUname) && password.equalsIgnoreCase(dbPword)) {
        return "Admin_home";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: If JSF works fine, there should not be a jsf tag on your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in the edited post:

```
    public void dbData(String UName, String PWord) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/unidb?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "Safia10122014");
        String SQL = "select `Username`, `Password` from `SPAS_Login_Details` where `Username` like 'MWR0025'";

        //String SQL = "select * from `SPAS_Login_Details` where `Username` = 'MWR0025' and `Password` = 'MWR0025'";
        //String SQLA = "select * from `SPAS_Login_Details` where `Username` = 'QD0040' and `Password` = 'QD0040'";
        //String SQLB = "select * from `SPAS_Login_Details` where `Username` = 'HB0041' and `Password` = 'HB0041'";
        //String SQLC = "select * from `SPAS_Login_Details` where `Username` = 'VV0042' and `Password` = 'VV0042'";
        //String SQLD = "select * from `SPAS_Login_Details` where `Username` = 'MA0043' and `Password` = 'MA0043'";
        //String SQLE = "select * from `SPAS_Login_Details` where `Username` = 'NF0044' and `Password` = 'NF0044'";

        Statement statement = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
        resultSet.next();
        dbUname = resultSet.getString(1);
        dbPword = resultSet.getString(2);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public String validation() {
    dbData(name, password);

    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(dbUname) && password.equalsIgnoreCase(dbPword)) {
        return "Admin_home";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your codes look fine, i think the reason why you are not directed to the  Admin_ home is because you haven't called the "checkValidUser" function.
It should be called here

if(rs.next()){
  checkValidUser():}

if no errors are found, the program should work correctly.

Comment: No luck, I updated to show my command button in the JSF page which might help figure out the problem.